# How to use Xgboost.DMatrix.set_info in combination with randomizedsearchcv?

Tags: xgboost, feature-selection, gridsearchcv

I am training an xgboost.Classifier, and I want to specify feature importance manually by using the feature_weights setting of the xgboost.DMatrix  option. However, I am not sure how to integrate this with the randomizedsearchcv package.

My code looks as posted below. In feature_weights I have (hardcoded for now) a np array with the feature weights. I realize that in order to use these feature weights for my xgboost model, I need to specify dtrain somewhere in the training process, such as : xgboost.train(params, **dtrain**, ... ) However as I am using randomsearchcv which automaticall calls xgboost.train, I am not sure how to specify this. I hope someone can help me! Thanks a lot in advance.

```
### TRAINING ####################################################################
def model_train(dataset, model):
    df = dataset
    # splitting the dataset
    X = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'revenue']
    y = df['revenue']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42) 
    # Verifying the numbers
    print("train set instances: " ,len(y_train))
    print("test set instances :", len(y_test))
    
    # create model
    feature_weights = np.ones(93, dtype = int)
    feature_weights[0:2] = 4
    dtrain = xgboost.DMatrix(X_train, y_train)
    dtrain.set_info(feature_weights=feature_weights)
    clf = model

    # find the best params:
    param_dist = {'learning_rate': [0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30],
                    'max_depth': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
                    'subsample': [1], # was 1.0
                    'min_child_weight': [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                    'gamma': [0.0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
                    'max_delta_step': [0],
                    'colsample_bytree': [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 1.0],
                    'colsample_bylevel': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
                    'n_estimators': [50, 70, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400], # is number of different trees
                    }

    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
    # Use random search to find the best hyperparameters, this balances the dataset automatically using stratified
    rand_search = RandomizedSearchCV(clf,
                                        param_distributions=param_dist,
                                        scoring='f1_macro', 
                                        n_jobs=-1,
                                        n_iter=10,
                                        cv=kfold,
                                        verbose=2,
                                        random_state=42)

    # Fit the random search object to the data
    rand_search.fit(X_train, y_train) 
    # Create a variable for the best model
    best_clf = rand_search.best_estimator_
```

I tried to include it in the param_dist, as 'dtrain':dtrain, but this did not work.